# Why do private setters behave differently to other private methods?

Tags: ruby

Here's an interesting case I can't seem to explain. It looks like private setters are 'kind of' private, but sometimes there are exceptions to that. Regular private methods seem to behave differently to private setters:

```
class TestClass
  def do
    self.foo = :bar # fine
    self.baz        # error
  end

  private

  def foo=(other)
    @foo = other
  end

  def baz
  end
end

TestClass.new.do
```

The above code sets `@foo` just fine, despite being called on an explicit `self`. Then it fails to call `#baz`, because `#baz` is a private method.

What's up with this?

Comment: Normally I would call `baz` without using the prefix `self`, and that should work in this instance. But I realize that doesn't answer your direct question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Private setters are special because otherwise they couldn't be called at all:

```
foo = :bar
```

Assigns to the local variable `foo`, it doesn't send the message `foo=`.

Note that setters aren't the only things which cannot be called without an explicit receiver. `+@`, `-@`, `!`, `~`, `[]`, `[]=`, `+`, `-`, `*`, `/`, `%`, `&`, `|`, `^`, `**`, `<<`, `>>`, `==`, `===`, `=~`, `!~`, `!=`, `<`, `>`, `<=`, `>=`, `<=>` and probably some others I forgot also cannot be called without an explicit receiver. And then there's stuff like `+=`, `<<=` and so on.

There need to be exceptions for all of those. Unfortunately, there are only exceptions for some of those.

It has been proposed to change the rules for `private` from

> Can only be called without an explicit receiver, except for [this long list of exceptions which is really complicated, and still not complete].

to

> Can only be called without an explicit receiver or the literal special variable `self` as receiver.

which preserves all the current properties of the definition (the most important one being that it can be determined statically at parse time).

[But so far, nothing has come of it.](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/11297#note-3)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't use `self` when using the setter method, it will instead assign the value to a local variable. [More details](https://content.pivotal.io/blog/private-setters-in-ruby-what-to-do).

In the code below, I've removed `self` from the assignment to foo, and you can see the the setter is not being used b/c `@foo` is `nil`:

```
  def do
    foo = :bar # fine
    baz        # error
    puts @foo  # prints nil
    puts foo   # prints 'bar'
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

That pretty much how the `private` works and it's the main difference between `private` and `protected` methods in ruby. You can't call `private` methods on instance of the class, even inside that class, while `protected` allows that.